# Error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Tags: c#, system.data.oracleclient

I'm trying to open OracleConnection microsoft provider (System.Data.OracleClient). And I'm getting this error only in RELEASE not in DEBUG

Comment: When do you get the error? On connection? After a query? As soon as the app starts?

Comment: can you show your code?  are you doing any multithreading?

Comment: Looks very similar: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/616087

Answer (score 0):

I had that error from computers using my software, which read and wrote basically all free bytes of hard disks (a recovery and deletion software). Back then (2009) I could track it down to a low-level problem of the harddisks of our customers. It never happened on a healthy disk. From that experience, and the missing of any question on your part, I would say it's a hard disk failure and you should test out if the error is reproductible on a fresh database on another physical computer.

If so, quickly change disks on that database server or whatever you're reading to / writing from and restore that machine from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem, problem was that I was referencing some DLL with unmanaged code and those DLL wasn't even used in my code, just when I removed them from reference everything worked fine.